# Is it possible to have a multi-line signature with HTML formatting?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, email

The signature setting in the Outlook Mail app only shows a single line. How can I enter multiple lines, with HTML formatted text if possible?

[image]

Comment: So what's your question here? Also, have you actually *tried* putting a new line in the signature?

Comment: If you want a new line, just hit the Enter key. Magic happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use a Multi line signature just press Enter key and type the next line.

Windows mobile **does support** Multi line signatures. You can see that from the screenshot below.

[image]

However the HTML support on Signature text is not working currently.